# Flex 4: Is it possible to show a Flex application on clicking a button in another flex app

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I remember launching a JFrame from within a JApplet.
I was wondering if I could do the same.
The requirement is like this

1. I have a screen estate just enough for a flex Button.
2. On clicking this button, I want to open another flex app which can be of larger real estate.
3. I dont want to open a new Browser window.

IS it remotely possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear and referencing java applets is even more confusing. I'd suggest you learn more about flex; free tutorial videos on the adobe website.   look into viewstacks, navigation and loading modules.